# How to put password mask in windows application c# Application

Tags: c#, windows

I am developing windows application to ask user to enter password in pop up box on that i am not able to put password mask,

if any on know could you please  help me out this  i am new to visual studio

```
string pin=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Input User Pin Number", "Pin Number", "" );
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. When you're programming, you edit text. You don't edit images. Images are difficult to manipulate and index, and a waste of bandwidth. Please copy the relevant code into your post and remove the link to the image.

Comment: Aside from the necessity to post code as *plain text*, it is not clear why you've posted code that is obviously written in VB.NET, yet titled and tagged your question C#. In the .NET world, there is relatively little difference between the two languages, but it's still customary to indicate your native dialect if you want the answers to take it into account.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way of doing this with an InputBox. (You'd have to install a hook before showing the dialog, and then when it was displayed, hunt around for its textbox control and change its styles.) Better to just say "can't". The InputBox wasn't designed to be customizable. In fact, it wasn't even designed to be used by .NET applications. It's an old classic VB thing, provided in the compatibility namespace merely to facilitate porting classic VB apps to VB.NET.

There is no real advantage in using it. Just create your own form with a label, maybe an icon, and a textbox. Set the textbox control's `UseSystemPasswordChar` property to true. (You could do as [rashfmnb suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35922964/366904) and set the `PasswordChar` property, but it is better to use the system's password character instead of your own, that way it always matches the user's expectations.)

Be sure to display your new form with the `ShowDialog` method so that it will be a modal dialog (blocking call), just like InputBox.

Answer (score 0):

user PasswordChar Property of the textbox

Comment: I don't think OP is using windows forms for the password prompt

Answer (score 0):

You can't mask the chars in an InputBox.

If you look at [Interaction.InputBox Method on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox(v=vs.100).aspx), there is no way to set it to be password input.

You will need to create a new Form, add your own Label and a TextBox, then set the PasswordChar property in the TextBox